# MySQL Select From Two Table per Rows of First Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables with like below codes:

**Table: Accounts**

```
id |    username    |   email   |   registered  
1   |   player1     | 123@asd.ad|   2012-05-03  
2   |   goodman     | 1345@bs.ad|   2012-06-03  
3 | goodbat | asdh@asd.d| 2012-06-05
```

**table:characters**

```
guid    |   account |   name    |   rank  
213     |   1       |   fres    |   2  
214     |   2       |   sdg2    |   3  
215     |   1       |   fgax    |   4  
216     |   3       |   zFvx |  8  
217     |   3       |   zsvx    |   2 
...
```

**I want to show accounts with their highest rank character with just one Query .**

**output**  (Show Accounts with their Highest rank character)

```
username : player1 | 123@asd.ad | char: fgax(4)  
username : goodman | 1345@bs.ad | char: sdg2(3)  
username : goodbat | 134s@bs.ad | char: zFvx(8)  
...
```

**My Query:**

```
SELECT username,email,id FROM accounts
```

Comment: You should make this question a little more descriptive such as naming your tables.  Is table1 the accounts table and what is the value in rank?  Is the rank value an integer value that we can compare?

Comment: Your sample output does not match your data.

Comment: I want to fix missing details but give error : (Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code.)

Comment: Details fixed now :) , sorry for missing details on first .

Comment: Have you tried any of our solutions? If so, comment on whether we were wrong or not so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT a.username, a.email, c.name
FROM Accounts a, characters c
WHERE a.id=c.account
ORDER BY MAX(c.rank) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.username, a.email, a.id, c.name
FROM accounts a 
JOIN chars c ON a.id = c.account 
ORDER BY a.rank DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
SELECT 
a.username as userName, 
a.email as email, 
a.id as id, 
c.name as name

FROM accounts a 
INNER JOIN chars c ON (a.id = c.accoun)t 
ORDER BY a.rank DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a table join. What table joins do is that they query 2 tables, in your case **Table1** and **table2**. Here is the query and it will be followed by the explanation.

```
SELECT `t1`.`username`, `t1`.`email`, `t2`.account 
FROM `Table1` `t1`, `table2` `t2` 
WHERE `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`account` ORDER BY `rank` DESC
LIMIT 0,3
```

LINE 1: SELECT...
    `t1`.`username` means username column from `t1`., and so on...and the `t1`, `t2` notation comes from...

LINE 2: FROM...
`Table1` `t1` means I am querying from **Table1**, and assigned it an alias or pointer `t1`. This is the same for how we assign **table2** to `t2`.

LINE 3: WHERE...
This means that you join the tables based on a common column. In this case, both **Table1** and **table2** share the same set of values - id for **Table1** and account for **table2**. Hence, you used the above line.

ORDER BY...
This means you want to arrange the records based on a certain criteria, in this case rank. There are  2 directions - ASC which means Ascending (smallest top) or DESC which means Descending.

LINE 4: LIMIT 0,3
This means I want to get the first row (0) and only 3 records. Hence, LIMIT 0,3

This is the most comprehensive explanation I could give.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT 
t1.username as userName, 
t1.email as email, 
concat(t2.name, '(', t2.rank, ')') as name
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.account 
ORDER BY t2.rank DESC
```